# hibernate-can't run " cfg.configure()" outside of method?

Tags: java, hibernate

due to the frequently insert event , (it's a chat room program)
it's always occurs "exception : java heap outOfMemory...."

and i think that it's cause from here

here is my correct code

```
public static boolean saveMethod(String userid,String username,String msg){
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.configure(); //here is correct
    SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try{
        ....jump

    transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(saveMsg);
        transaction.commit();
        return true;
    }catch(Exception e){
        return false;
    }

}
```

so i change the method to that

```
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.configure();// error here
    SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    public static boolean setPublicMsg(String userid,String username,String msg){
        //insert
    }
```

> Syntax error on token "configure", Identifier expected after this
>   token

how can i write here ?
or anyone have some idea about the "exception : java heap outOfMemory...." in hibernate?

i'm try to change the tomcat setting, but it's not working

thanks !

Comment: Yes, in Java, you can't have arbitrary statements inside a class definition. Only variable and method declarations, static and instance blocks, and constructors. That's extremely basic Java syntax, and you should practice on basic stuff before using Hibernate, which is an advances, complex beast, that you're not using as you should. At least read the documentation: the configuration and the session factory should be created only once, and be reused for the whole program lifetime. Recreating it every time is like building a new 747 each time you have to fly.

Comment: I solved this problem by build up the HibernateUtil .
thank you for reply my question. I'm reflect myself for my unpracticed programming skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by looking at your `saveMethod()`, it looks like you are creating `configuration` and `sessionFactory` per each save call. You can simply avoid this.

When your application starts, you can build the `sessionFactory` once and reuse as much as you need.

For example, you can use a HibernateUtil class to get the `sessionFactory` as below.

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null ) {
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Then in your `saveMethod()` you get the `sessionFactory` as below.

```
public static boolean saveMethod(String userid,String username,String msg){
    SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I solved this problem by build up the HibernateUtil. thank you for help !
I have to learn more about hibernate concept. thank you!